# Page offset changes based on if elements are in SVG

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I am making an application that makes a custom map with user defined points using SVG. When there are no points in the database then no `<image>` elements are added to the SVG, but if so then they are added. The problem is that the offset of the `<svg>` element is different when there are `<image>` elements inside then when nothing is inside. This messes with the calculation when the user adds a new point. The width and height of the SVG are fixed. Is there something else that I need to add to the calculation?

EDIT: This is code used to get and then calculate offset. `#svg` is now container element:

```
offset=$("#svg").offset();
xAdjust=event.pageX-offset.left;
yAdjust=event.pageY-offset.top;
```

Comment: Try adding a container outside svg and check its offset.

Comment: @KTU Adding the container did make the offset consistent. However, the Y axis calculation is still quite a bit off. The point ends up being lower than where the mouse was clicked in the svg.